# Looking for a simpler way to check if multiple properties & methods in an object are undefined

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
    if(eform[funcName] !== undefined){
        if(eform[funcName].init !== undefined){
            //finally do something
        }
    }
```

I'm first checking to see if the `eform` object has the property specified by the variable `funcName`. If it does, then I need to check whether that property has an `init` method.

Is there any way to combine these into a single `if` statement? Or perhaps something even more elegant than that?

Comment: hasOwnProperty might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Short-Circuit evaluation:

```
if (eform[funcName] !== undefined && eform[funcName].init !== undefined)
```

If `eform[funcName]` is undefined the statement if false and `eform[funcName].init` is never checked. Depending on preference/readability this following is vaild as well:

```
if (eform[funcName] && eform[funcName].init)
```

Answer (score 2):

think that one is better:

```
if(eform[funcName] !== undefined && eform[funcName].init !== undefined){
  //some code
}
```

if the first condition is false than the second condition wont be checked.

Comment: thanks. I gave the answer to IAbstractDownvoteFactory just because of his additional note regarding the fact that I don't need to do === undefined.

Answer (score 1):

JS has a new, elegant way to achieve this - The [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator

It looks like this:

```
if (eform?[funcName]?.init !== undefined) {
  // do something
}
```

Works with all modern browsers.
But babel has not yet added support for this op natively and throws a compilation error. In that case, babel suggests:

> Add @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
> (https://git.io/vb4Sk) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel
> config to enable transformation.